# How to mirror a selected area/window in primary display to second display

Tags: macos, mirroring

I want to project only a selected area or an application window to the external monitor. Is there any software that can do that kind of thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### [OBS — Open Broadcaster Software](https://obsproject.com)

1. In macOS System Settings → Displays, select **Extended display** as the Use as option.
2. In OBS, click the + button under **Sources** and choose **macOS Screen Capture**.

   [image]
3. In the popup choose 'Create new' and choose **OK**
4. Select the display to capture from and choose **OK**

   [image: Properties modal]
5. Use the red handles to resize your Display Capture source appropriately within the black ‘display’ (preview) in the OBS window. This is how/where your display will show on the mirror.

   [image]
6. Right-click anywhere in the preview and choose ‘Fullscreen Projector (Preview)’, then select your external display to output to.

   [image]